# How to shutdown self-hosted Apache CXF web service?

Tags: java, cxf

I have a console application which can be briefly described with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean sfb = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    sfb.setResourceClasses(DummyService.class);
    sfb.setResourceProvider(DummyService.class, new SingletonResourceProvider(new DummyServiceImpl()));
    sfb.setProvider(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    sfb.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9000/");
    BindingFactoryManager manager = sfb.getBus().getExtension(BindingFactoryManager.class);
    JAXRSBindingFactory bindingFactory = new JAXRSBindingFactory();
    bindingFactory.setBus(sfb.getBus());
    manager.registerBindingFactory(JAXRSBindingFactory.JAXRS_BINDING_ID, bindingFactory);
    Server server = sfb.create();       
    server.stop(); // here
}
```

I run this program from Eclipse and I expect it to finish immediately, because I have `server.stop()` right in the end. This line of code is executed by application remains alive, so I have to shutdown it manually. Here's the log CXF prints to the console:

```
Aug 13, 2012 10:51:10 PM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://0.0.0.0:9000/
2012-08-13 22:51:10.598:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.5.3.v20111011
2012-08-13 22:51:10.646:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000 STARTING
2012-08-13 22:51:10.662:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler{,null}
2012-08-13 22:51:10.663:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler{,null}
```

After a call to `server.stop()` application is still running, but server doesn't respond any requests, so it feels like I need to shutdown something else.

What is a proper way to stop it?

**Update**

```
server.stop();
server.destroy();
```

Also doesn't work.

**Update**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed with

```
server.stop();
server.destroy();
sfb.getBus().shutdown(true)
```

Feels like dirty hack.

Comment: The CXF bus is kind of like a singleton so it sticks around so becareful because when you shutdown the bus you might shut it down for other CXF servers that are using it in your JVM. Anyway the above + creating and then setting my own bus in sfb fixed all sorts of errors I would get when destroying and recreating my server within the same JVM instance.

Comment: Maybe `org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory#destroyForPort` could be alternative

Answer (score 0):

From javadoc (http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/JAXRSServerFactoryBean.html):

> [..]This will start a server for you and register it with the
>   ServerManager. Note you should explicitly close the Server created when finished with it:

```
myServer.close();
myServer.destroy();
```

Comment: There's no method `close()` in my `org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server` class. I've updated the question.

Comment: There's no method `close()` in `Server`: http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/endpoint/Server.html

Comment: i looked into ServerImpl in cxf 2.6.1 and close() is gone. But there also isn't anything besides stop() and destroy(). Maybe some other part of the application keeps on running? Have you checked the logs for shutdown, cleanup or error messages? I don't see other reasons right now, sry.

Comment: Absolutely no other code, no other threads. Other classes are just DTOs and service implementation with operations like `a+b` - that's why I'm confused.